# ui-router not working after minify with Gulp

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, minify

I make app with Angular and use Gulp to minify all file css, javascript. But if I run `gulp build` to minify and then run file 'index.html' in dist folder, ui-router not load template. In file html, tag a still like this : `<a ui-sref='link'> LINK </a>`. It is kind of you to help me!
this is link code:

app.js
https://gist.github.com/quyen91/d4ca009bb0be0e42a5a9dbded76ec45a

gulpfile.js
https://gist.github.com/quyen91/bd04688302847a964e16586f9b468d29

error: https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/1EjGpl8T.png

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: Error: Cannot find module 'undefined'
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module angularShopingCartApp due to:

I have added two link gulpfile.js and app.js. please see and help me.

Comment: check whether order of concating the files are correct.

Comment: Use [gulp-useref](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-useref) to preserve the order of concatenated files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ui Router and many factories usually stop working because when we don't minify, we always inject the correct names of their providers into the parameters of controllers or config or run or anything else.. But when minified, what happens is

```
run(function($state,$rootScope,$http){})
would become 
run(function(x,y,z){})
```

This causes the problem..

So it is always a good practice to write the names of providers separately.
Thus the function becomes

```
run(['$state','$rootScope','$http',function($state,$rootScope,$http){}]);
to 
run(['$state','$rootScope','$http',function(x,y,z){}]);
```

but here the providers of the variables are correct so it won't cause any error.

In your case the run method should be like

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', 'auth', 'jwtHelper', '$location', 'store',function($rootScope, $state, auth, jwtHelper, $location, store) {


    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function() {
    // Get the JWT that is saved in local storage
    // and if it is there, check whether it is expired.
    // If it isn't, set the user's auth state
    var token = store.get('token');
    if (token) {
      if (!jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token)) {
        if (!auth.isAuthenticated) {
          auth.authenticate(store.get('profile'), token);
        }
      }
    }
    else {
      // Otherwise, redirect to the home route
      $location.path('/about');
    }
  });
```

And the config should start as

```
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 'authProvider', '$httpProvider', '$locationProvider',
  'jwtInterceptorProvider',function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, authProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider,
  jwtInterceptorProvider) {
.....
}]);
```

Comment: I tried. But It is not working. It seem to be problem in order file minified. I am trying find solution.

Comment: the order of the minified files in gulp should be exactly the same as that in your index.html script src="". Following this order is assurance that it was working when it wasn't minified.. If its not working after being minified, the order shall not be an issue..

Comment: So,can you check my gulpfile.js? And you think what is problem?

Comment: The only problems possible after minification is the one of unpr or the unknown provider... that is because i told you.. The minification changes the variable names but the things mentioned as string doesn't change at all.. So the most important thing to check is that you must declare all your factories or services and controllers and any other stuff such as directives in the manner described above.

Comment: @babie I went through your gulp file and app.js .. The error is certainly of the injector... There is a problem in names after minification.

Comment: authProvider.on('loginSuccess'),  authProvider.on('authenticated',  authProvider.on('logout'), are also not defined properly.

Comment: Found the solution? @babie

Comment: I haven't. I am trying to fix it.

Comment: oh, I didn't see your mesage @Tirthraj Barot .This is my index file
[link](https://gist.github.com/quyen91/e720b9f70ab35afa1de3a39561999756)

Comment: Then why didn't you include all other files into gulp such as angular-touch.js,angular-material.js,angular-ui-router.js,angular-jwt.js,auth0.js,auth0-lock.js,auth0-angular.js,firebase.js,etc ?

Comment: may be you would have given them as *.js ... No problem.. just check whether all of them are covered or not... and check the injections.. thats it..

Comment: Please do not forget to mark the answer correct if it has helped you ... @babie

Comment: You are right, problem is not in order. It is in dependency injection, when I delete some some dependencies, it work like a charm, now I know what break my app.Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.run` and `.config` block isn't minification safe.

Try this one for `.run` :

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', 'auth', 'jwtHelper', '$location', 'store', function($rootScope, $state, auth, jwtHelper, $location, store) {


    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function() {
    // Get the JWT that is saved in local storage
    // and if it is there, check whether it is expired.
    // If it isn't, set the user's auth state
    var token = store.get('token');
    if (token) {
      if (!jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token)) {
        if (!auth.isAuthenticated) {
          auth.authenticate(store.get('profile'), token);
        }
      }
    }
    else {
      // Otherwise, redirect to the home route
      $location.path('/about');
    }
  });

}]);
```

Do the same for `config`.

Comment: Thank you. But it is still not working when I change like this.

Comment: @babie seems like angular and firebase missing too, did you referenced those libs?

Comment: stupid question, but is your app working when minfication commented out?

Comment: [here](https://gist.github.com/eenagy/c2c5e488a1e2600a636e056273c95c2b) some clean out, does this solve it?

Comment: ok, has one last idea, if you use git and minification worked at some point (and commited that), you can use git bisect for finding what went wrong

Comment: Thanks. I will use it to track.